# How to handle Podio 'Item' Deleted in ETL?

Tags: etl, podio

I'm replicating data from Podio to our snowflake instance using Podio's apis. (if anyone is interested in that python/Mage code just let me know, and i can share it).

I've now ran into a slight hiccup. It appears users are deleting Items in the UI. So 2 questions.

1. Does Podio Hard Delete the Items? (im not seeing any response from the Items endpoint of a "deletedAt" so makes me feel like its hard deleted)
2. If it is hard deleted, Is the recommended approach to set up a webhook that Podio will call each time an item is deleted?

What I have tried so far.
I've looked at their docs, and couldn't see anything about hard deletes or not.
I've started a chat with Podio's support, and they pushed me here to get my answer